# Is there a rule to the terms of a falling factorial?

Tags: polynomials, factorial, multinomial-coefficients

$\require{cancel}$I discovered that $n!=\xcancel{(n)_{n-1}}n^{\underline{n-1}}=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(3)(2)$. I have expanded a few examples:

$$2!=\xcancel{(2)_1}2^{\underline{1}}=2\\
3!=\xcancel{(3)_2}3^{\underline{2}}=3(3-1)=3^2-3=9-3=6\\
4!=\xcancel{(4)_3}4^{\underline{3}}=4(4-1)(4-2)=4^3-3\cdot4^2+2\cdot4=64-48+8=24\\
5!=\xcancel{(5)_4}5^{\underline{4}}=5(5-1)(5-2)(5-3)=5^4-6\cdot5^3+11\cdot5^2-6\cdot5\\=625-750+275-30=120$$

My question is what rule is there to determine the proper coefficients for the expansion of the falling factorial? For example, let's say we have coefficients $a, b, c, d, e$ such that

$$\xcancel{(x)_8}x^{\underline{8}}=x^8-\binom{8}{2}x^7+ax^6-bx^5+cx^4-dx^3+ex^2-7!x$$

What rule enables me to choose those coefficients without multiplying the factors together?

Incidentally, the full polynomial is

$$\xcancel{(x)_8}x^{\underline{8}}=x^8-28x^7+322x^6-1960x^5+6769x^4-13132x^3+13068x^2-5040x$$

*Edit: Since there was initially some confusion as to the notation's meaning, I have canceled the previous notation and added other notation that has (I hope) only one use. I hope this clears things up. I definitely meant Falling Factorial, but as it has been brought to my attention that the symbol I chose may have misled some people, I thought this change might be necessary.*

Comment: Why do you want to expand ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I was using an example, but I wanted to expand the product $n(n-1)\cdots(n-(n-1)+1)$.

Comment: Oh, @ClaudeLeibovici, I'm sorry. You asked **why,** not **what.** Well, I just thought it might be easier to conceptualize the factorial of $n$ as an expanded polynomial of degree $n-1$ than as an iterated product.

Comment: For the _rising_ factorial, I believe they are the Stirling numbers of the first kind (also with inconsistent notation).

Answer (score 1):

The present discussion is polluted by the confusion of unfortunate symbols for falling and rising factorials as well as the Pochhammer symbol. This has been well underlined in the comments. In order to make it clear to everybody, an excerpt from WolframMathWorld is attached below.
So, without using the Pochhammer symbol, the formula is :
$$ x(x+1)(x+2)…(x+n-1) = s(n,n)x^n-s(n,n-1)x^{n-1}+…+(-1)^{n-1}s(n,1)x  $$
$$ x(x-1)(x-2)…(x-n+1) = s(n,n)x^n+s(n,n-1)x^{n-1}+…+s(n,1)x  $$
where $s(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of the first kind.
Using the Stirling’s symbol $s(n,k)$ is the simplest way to represent analytically the coefficients of the polynomial. Of course, if the goal is to simplify the numerical computation, using the Stirling numbers  is not an advantage in the practical viewpoint.

[image]

Comment: I realize that I'm using a symbol that has two different meanings. For this reason, please interpret $(x)_n$ in the context in which I have used it as Falling Factorial, or $x^{\underline{n}}$, which is **not** to be confused with $x^n$, the power notation. If you find the notation confusing, so do I.

Comment: Sure ! I am afraid to have possibly made a confusion somewhere in my own answers !!!

Comment: But are the Stirling numbers still used with $$x^{\underline{n}}=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$$ (falling factorial)? The formula you gave is for the rising factorial. Is it just the signs that are different?

Comment: Apparently they are! I checked the formula for one of my falling factorials, substituting + signs everywhere, and starting with 2, and the terms added up to the correct value.

Comment: That gives me an idea! $$n!=1^{(n)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{|s(n,i)|}$$

Comment: I agree with you. I completed my answer above so that the formulas for falling and rising factorials can be easily compared.

Comment: Here's a little table I put together of the first 8 rows of the Stirling Triangle of the First Kind. It occurred to me that the polynomial utilizes the numbers in reverse order.
$\begin{matrix}
&&&&&&&1\\
&&&&&&-1&&1\\
&&&&&2&&-3&&1\\
&&&&-6&&11&&-6&&1\\
&&&24&&-50&&35&&-10&&1\\
&&-120&&274&&-225&&85&&-15&&1\\
&720&&-1764&&1624&&-735&&175&&-21&&1\\
-5040&&13068&&-13132&&6769&&-1960&&322&&-28&&1
\end{matrix}$

Comment: Each row adds up to a factorial.

Comment: The absolute values, that is.

Comment: Each row (signed values) totals to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

@ user3255936 : There is a risk of confusion between your symbol and the Pochhammer's symbol which is widely used.
The Pochhammer polynomial is defiened as :

$(x)_n = x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n-1)$

It is possible to write your "falling factorial" on the Pochhammer's form. For example:
$(5)(5-1)(5-2)(5-3) = (5-3)(5-2)(5-1)(5) = (2)(3)(4)(5)=  (x)_n$  with $x=2$ and $n=4$

The series development of the Pochhammer polynomial involves the Stirling numbers of the first kind. See Eq.(8) in : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html
So, the coefficients that you are looking for are related to these Stirling numbers.

Comment: The Pochhammer symbols are not used with consistent notation, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) uses $(x)_n = x(x-1)\dotsb(x-n+1)$ in its article, like the OP.

Comment: Thanks to draw attention on the possible confusion due to the same notation used for

Comment: thanks to draw attention to the confusing notation.

Comment: Sorry for the preceeding uncomplete posts due to unexpected breakdown of transmission. Thanks to draw attention on the confusing notation. Abramowitz and Stegun, J.Spanier use it as the "rising factorial" as well as implemented in Mathematica and in WolframAlpha. That is the notation I am used to. Other authors use the same notation for the "falling factorial". So, one have to be carefull and check which notation each author uses.

Comment: When $n=x-1$, the last factor in a falling factorial is 2. But would you rather I had used $_nP_{n-1}$ notation instead? Mathematically, they're equivalent.

Comment: I believe you're getting the notation $(x)_n$ confused with $(x)^{(n)}$, which is the rising factorial.

Comment: If I need to compute the Stirling numbers for this, I think that would increase the complexity. I'm almost better off multiplying $n(n-1)!$ because there's too much computation for each term's coefficient! In the words of Winnie-the-Pooh, "Oh bother!"

Comment: @Daniel, the website that JJacquelin linked to also uses $(x)_n$ as falling factorial further down the page, and distinguishes it from the rising factorial, $(x)^{(n)}$. The article contains ambiguities.

Comment: Sorry, that symbol should have been $x^{(n)}$, not $(x)^{(n)}$.

Comment: And remember, a formula in MathJaX on this board should be surrounded with dollar signs (\$) for inline formulas and double dollar signs (\$\$) for displayed formulas. The MathJaX won't render otherwise.